# PL/SQL Expression to get differences between hours

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an application in Apex where the user selects the start time `F1` of an event and the end time `F2`, and the result should be displayed in a third text field `F3`.

**How can I perform the operation of subtracting `F1` and `F2` using a PL / SQL function?**

For example 7:00 and 7:30 and the result is 30 min.

The time is entered as text, so I use `to_date` to convert the two fields to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle there is no timediff function, but you can calculate the difference easily applying normal arithmetic operations.

I use this example, where I am using two input variables that you must replace with your APEX items, and use the date mask you want to. In my example I am using YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.

You can also convert this to a function instead and put the P3 Item as a result of the function.

```
declare 
v_start_date varchar2(40) := ':P1_START_DATE';
v_end_date   varchar2(40) := ':P1_END_DATE';
v_result     number;
begin
   select ( to_date(':P1_END_DATE','yyyymmddhh24miss') - 
            to_date(':P1_START_DATE','yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 * 60 
   into v_result from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line ( v_result );
end;
/
   from dual ;
```

With a function

```
create or replace function my_date_diff ( p_end_date in varchar2 , p_start_date in varchar2 ) return number 
is 
 v_result number;
begin
  select ( to_date(p_end_date ,'yyyymmddhh24miss') - 
            to_date(p_star_date,'yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 * 60 
   into v_result from dual;
  return v_result ;
end;
```

**Remember to apply the date mask corresponding to your ITEM in Apex**

Answer (score 0):

As said before before in oracle we do not have predefined functions to find out time difference and we need to do by our self

How ever I have some alternatives with my work experience which differs only in terms of readability as compare to the answer already available

```
/*
   with fields having already in timestamp format
*/
WITH time_difference AS
 (SELECT timestamp'2020-08-04 07:00:00' start_dt
        ,timestamp'2020-08-04 07:30:00' end_dt
  FROM   dual)
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) hrs
      ,EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) mins
      ,EXTRACT(SECOND FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) secs
      ,end_dt - start_dt diff_interval
FROM   time_difference;
```

---

```
/*
  with fields having date, subtracting them results in a number,
  so we can case them to timestamps and do as above
*/
WITH field_in_dates AS
 (SELECT to_date('04.08.2020 07:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_dt
        ,to_date('04.08.2020 07:30:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')end_dt
  FROM   dual),
time_difference AS
 (SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(start_dt,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') start_dt
        ,to_timestamp(to_char(end_dt,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') end_dt
  FROM   field_in_dates)
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) hrs
      ,EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) mins
      ,EXTRACT(SECOND FROM(end_dt - start_dt)) secs
      ,end_dt - start_dt diff_interval
FROM   time_difference;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a slight alternative. Instead of converting you input strings to a date convert then to timestamps. Timestamps, like dates, can be directly subtracted. However, subtracting dates results in a floating point value, which can never be perfectly represented in binary, so 30 may wind up as 29.99999...) where as subtracting timestamps always results in an exact interval. So (assuming time formats do not include seconds just 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'). See [full example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74ac57f1515e8a876c4c2b5c2ac14b00).

```
create or replace 
function event_duration (p_start_date varchar, p_end_date varchar)
  return varchar2
is
    v_time_diff interval day to second;
    v_time_seg  integer;
    v_result    varchar2(40) := ' ';    
begin
    v_time_diff := to_timestamp(p_end_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') 
                 - to_timestamp(p_start_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ; 
    
    v_time_seg :=  extract(day from v_time_diff);         
    if v_time_seg > 0 
    then 
       v_result := to_char(v_time_seg, 'FM999') || ' days' || ' ';
    end if ; 
    
    v_time_seg :=  extract(hour from v_time_diff);         
    if v_time_seg > 0 
    then 
       v_result :=  v_result || to_char(v_time_seg, 'FM999') || ' hours' || ' ';
    end if ; 
    
    v_time_seg := extract(minute from v_time_diff);
    if v_time_seg  > 0 
    then 
       v_result := v_result || to_char(v_time_seg,'FM99' ) || ' minutes' ;
    end if ;  
   
   return trim(v_result) ;  
end event_duration;
```